# How can I populate an embedded website form with URL parameters using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, squarespace, zoho

I have a Zoho form embedded on a Squarespace site and I need to populate some fields with URL parameters in Javescript. I'm using the following code to get the parameters:

```
<script>       function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
</script>
```

and then to set the parameters to variables:

```
  var campaign1 = getUrlVars()["campaign"];
  alert(campaign1);
```

So that gets the parameter named 'campaign' in the url and assigns it to 'campaign1'. The alert is just to show that it is working, and it is. Then I want to run this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://forms.zohopublic.com/....j7Q?campaign="+campaign1 id="ZFScript">  alert(campaign1); </script>
```

But no matter what I do I can't get that part to reference the variable in the 'src=' section, but I can reference it in the 'alert(campaign1);' immediately after.

I also tried this, which was meant to save the whole URL to a variable named 'site' and just run 'src=site', but that didn't work either.

```
<script>       function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;

}
  var campaign1 = getUrlVars()["campaign"];
  var site = "https://forms.zohopublic.com....j7Q?campaign="+campaign1
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src=site id="ZFScript"> alert(site);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to write some js code where it is not parsed/rendered/executed.

The js code will be executed inside `<script>` tags or `onEvent` attributes. For instance *onclick* or *onload*.

So what you want to do is execute some js code inside a *script* tag that will generate a script tag with the dynamic src attribute you are trying to achieve. This is a way of doing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // [...]
  var campaign1 = getUrlVars()["campaign"];
  var site = "https://forms.zohopublic.com....j7Q?campaign="+campaign1;

  // create a script node
  var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  // set its src attribute
  scriptElement.setAttribute('src', site);
  // add you new script node to your document
  document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
</script>
```

Comment: Dionys,
While that does set 'site' correctly, the Zoho form is no longer embedded on the page. Is there a part I am missing to this?

Comment: @JoeCuningham I don't know Zoho, can't help you with this part sry